# Best way to show video in GatsbyJS as front, node js as back and mysql for DB

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, video-streaming

I am beginner at this so maybe you could suggest me what would be best way or any way how to stream videos in gatsby js app. It uses node js back end and all data is stored in mysql. The idea is to store videos as BLOBs in mysql and convert them back to video file on client side. I was wondering maybe the files should be stored somewhere else to increase performance. 
The main idea is to have a training site, where client selects lessons, which includes several pdfs and video files, so there would be multiple requests as client proceeds through the lesson

Comment: Media assets, like video, audio, images, are best stored as files in a content delivery network. When you store them in a DBMS as BLOBs, all of a sudden your DBMS becomes the bottleneck for delivering them to your users.  Sure, you can deliver a dozen streams that way. But thousands? not so much. Most people put that kind of material on a filesystem and store the URLs to the assets in the DBMS. Web servers have a quarter-century of optimization effort in them for delivering large files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some cloud services that are able to store videos and images professionally.

For example, cloudinary or AWS S3.

You can use MySQL blob as well but I don't recommend it because you can do it in an easier way. 
Using clodinary, you can make video accessible public but also private.
Enjoy clodinary!

Comment: I used cloudinary in LMS similar to your project and the performance was amazing.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a CDN to store and deliver your static content like images and videos. I don't think storing as Blob would work very well, you would probably have to completely download the video, and then play it on the client side.

If you want to have a youtube-like video streaming experience, you'll need a server that serves your video, something like Wowza stream